# Create matplotlib PolyCollection colormap mapping each cell to a color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 2D slice of a 3D figure with matplotlib [PolyCollection](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection), but I want to set a different color for each cell.  Is there a way to easily create a colormap to accomplish this?

I have a set of vertices I'm plotting then using the `array` argument to put an 2D array inside these vertices.  I also have a 2D list that holds the RGB value for each cell.  How can I generate a colormap from this 2D RGB list to pair with the PolyCollection?

For example:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
colors = [[(.2, .2, .3), (0, 0, 0)], [(.5, .5, .5), (.6, .3, .8)]]
```

I want the cell at (0, 0) to be (.2, .2, .3) and (0, 1) to be (0, 0, 0).

I'm guessing I need some combination of a [Normalize](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize)
instance and a
[ListedColormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap).

Alternatively, is there a way to just pass an array of RGB values to
PolyCollection as the `array` argument so that each 'value' is simply the color
of the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a sequence of 2D colors, you can use the `facecolors` kwarg (or equivalently `collection.set_facecolors(rgb_seq)`.

However, if you've made the `PolyCollection` through `ax.pcolor` or otherwise called `collection.set_array(some_data)` in another way, you'll need to disable the scalar-color-mapping behavior by calling `collection.set_array(None)`.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rgb = np.random.random((100, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
coll = ax.pcolor(np.zeros((10, 10)))

# If we left out the "array=None", the colors would still be controlled by the
# values of the array we passed in, and the "facecolors" kwarg would be
# ignored. This is equivalent to calling `coll.set_array(None)` and then
# `coll.set_facecolors(rgb)`.
coll.set(array=None, facecolors=rgb)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ha!  That explains it.  I didn't know `collection.set_array(None)` would turn off the scalar color mapping!  I ended up getting a clunky version working, but this is much better. My previous version created a 1D array of indexes and a `ListedColormap` with all the colors. Then, I 'plotted' the 1D array of indexes with that colormap. You're solution is WAY less work!

Comment: @durden2.0 - You're not the first person to be tripped up by the scalar color mapping vs facecolors difference.  It's a moderately common gotcha that manifests in a few different ways.  Glad to help, regardless!