# How to modify the facecolors of hexbin plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to fine tune the color of individual cells in a hexbin plot.

I have tried to use the method `set_facecolors` from [`PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) to alter the color of an individual cell but this does not appear to work.

Example: this should result in a hexbin with a red cell in the center:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = y = np.linspace(0.,1.,10)
pts=np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x,y,indexing='ij')).reshape(2,-1).T
z = np.zeros_like(pts[:,0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
hb = ax.hexbin(pts[:,0],pts[:,1], C=z, gridsize=(5,3), vmin=-1., edgecolors='white')
ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])

ax.figure.canvas.draw()
fcolors = hb.get_facecolors()
fcolors[31] = [1., 0., 0., 1.]
hb.set_facecolors(fcolors)

plt.show()
```

[image: Hexbin plot should feature a red cell in its center]

Any idea on how to set the facecolor of individual cells?

Comment: See also [Constructing a hexagonal heat-map with custom colors in each cell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70443427/12046409)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the colors are set via a colormap (hence the `C=z` parameter in `ax.hexbin()`). To change individual colors, you need to disable that behavior. That can be achieved by setting the "array" of the `PolyCollection` to `None` (see also Joe Kington's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29000246/12046409)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np;

x = y = np.linspace(0., 1., 10)
pts = np.vstack(np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')).reshape(2, -1).T
z = np.zeros_like(pts[:, 0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
hb = ax.hexbin(pts[:, 0], pts[:, 1], C=z, gridsize=(5, 3), vmin=-1., edgecolors='white')
ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])

ax.figure.canvas.draw()

fcolors = hb.get_facecolors()
fcolors[31] = [1., 0., 0., 1.]
hb.set(array=None, facecolors=fcolors)

plt.show()
```

[image: changing individual colors in a hexbin]